# How can I show an alert if the jQuery filter method cannot find the result

Tags: jquery, search, filter, alert

I have a jQuery problem with showing an alert if the result cannot be found with a filter method.

#search is a text input field for searching. This code could show the HTML element contains the value being searched in #search.

```js
$('#search_icon').click(function() {
  var sSearch = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();

  $("#results #card").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(sSearch) > -1)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're required to show the complete minimal scenario, which in this case would include at least a little HTML. Also, there's no code here relating to an alert. Please revise the demo above to be more complete.

Comment: Protip: Use `let` and `const` in 2024, not `var`.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to call a `filter` function over something `$("#results #card")` that is expected to return one element only since the id cannot be duplicated.

So instead of selecting the cards by id you may use a class `card` and the selector `.card`.

Now to be exact, using `filter` is pretty useless here since it's supposed to *Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.* You are actually just iterating over the list and toggling the visibility of each element according to the condition given. Despite the filter function would still make the job done, it would be more appropriate to use `each` instead.

Here's a working demo:

```js
$('#search_icon').click(function() {
  var sSearch = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();

  $("#results .card").each(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(sSearch) > -1)
  });
});
```

```css
#results{
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

.card{
  border: solid 1px;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 1em;
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" type="text">
<button id="search_icon">search</button>

<div id="results">
  <div class="card">a</div>
  <div class="card">b</div>
  <div class="card">c</div>
  <div class="card">d</div>
  <div class="card">e</div>
</div>
```